# Why so little discussion of Instant Pots?

Tags: discussion

In the web as a whole, I see lots of chatter about recipes for instant pots,  mostly too-long videos or stream of consciousness blogs filled with popups and spam.  So I looked here, hoping to learn in peace and quiet, but found only six questions tagged instant-pot.  Why so few?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe because you came here with the wrong assumption of our scope?

I offer you two possible explanations:

1. We don’t “discuss” and we don’t allow straight recipe requests on the main site. So a lot of what creates a lively discussion about the device elsewhere on the Internet would be plainly off-topic here.
2. The Instant Pot is a “relatively new” piece of kitchen equipment. While introduced in 2010, the “hype” is a rather recent phenomenon. Maybe users simply haven’t had that many questions yet (that they couldn’t solve via the aforementioned channels)?

So what does that mean for you? We are certainly not sending you away, instead we are encouraging you to post your questions on the main site and let the community answer them. We do have a few users that own and use an Instant Pot and could certainly help. Just make sure you familiarize yourself with the [What questions can I ask about here?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page of our help center. For less restricted chatter and discussions, we also have our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16/the-frying-pan).

Comment: Glad I asked on Meta instead of the main site.  Eventually I'll know enough of the basics of instant pots to ask meaningful within-scope questions here.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I have an Instant Pot and I love it. It figures prominently in the first set of videos I'm working on for YouTube.

You can absolutely ask questions revolving around the Instant Pot, and you can use what you know of the Instant Pot to answer questions that may not mention the Instant Pot. The link Stephie posted summarizes what is and is not "on-topic".

If you are struggling to form a question that you want to ask regarding the Instant Pot, come to chat and ask not necessarily for *the answer* to the question, but for advice about how to ask it.